# Corner by UIBezierPath for flexible View (View can increase width height by content)

Tags: ios

I am new in iOS. I am make a chat application. The image below is the table message. In each cell, I set 4 corners for `messageView` and it display correct

```
self.messageView.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0;
```

[image]

Now, I want some my message only have 3 corners (top-left, bottom-left, bottom-right) and some message have 3 corners (bottom-left, bottom-right, top-right) - like facebook messenger
so I user `UIBezierPath` for each cell.
But my message don't display full content. 
However, when I scroll up/down, the cell recreate and it displays correct.

```
UIBezierPath *maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:self.messageView.bounds byRoundingCorners:(UIRectCornerTopLeft | UIRectCornerBottomLeft | UIRectCornerBottomRight) cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(10.0, 10.0)];

CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
maskLayer.frame = self.bounds;
maskLayer.path  = maskPath.CGPath;
self.messageView.layer.mask = maskLayer;
```

I think my problem is:
When I set the conners by `UIBezierPath` for my `self.messageView`, the `self.messageView` not finished draw yet. so `self.messageView.bounds` return wrong value.
But I don't know how to fix it.

Any help would be great appreciated

Comment: Have you tried `sizeToFit`?

Comment: @schmidt9 please guide me where I should put the `sizeToFit`?

Comment: Please read https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/sizeToFit

Comment: @ schmidt9, I try to call sizeToFit in many place in my code, but it don't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't seems that you are updating the man in the -layoutSubviews method. 
Added layer doesn't know how to deal with your view, so you need to change their size in layoutSubviews of the view that is applying it.

Keep a reference to the mask path and update it, always call super before that.

Comment: thank you. I solve it, by update the corner inside `layoutSubView`

Answer (score 1):

Try this!!!

```
    UIBezierPath *maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:self.messageView.bounds byRoundingCorners:(UIRectCornerTopLeft | UIRectCornerBottomLeft | UIRectCornerBottomRight) cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(10.0, 10.0)];

    CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
    // maskLayer.frame = self.bounds;  

    maskLayer.frame = self.messageView.bounds; // Try this.
    maskLayer.path  = maskPath.CGPath;
    self.messageView.layer.mask = maskLayer;
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: I tried it. it's working fine.. add this. [self setNeedsDisplay];

Comment: my problem is in the tableview cell, and the cell can increase height. in your image, your view height is fixed

Comment: Thank you. but I see your tableview cell is same height, and it not depends on the text
but in my problem, my tableview cell have different height depends on the content inside. hope you can check it again

Comment: in your tableview code now .if you make you tableview cell height depends on the text, you will see my problem. i'm sure